# How to eject bot from Telegram group

Tags: telegram

I've a bot in a Telegram group and I want to eject it.

The way I would use with a user does not work.

How to eject the bot from the group?

Comment: Have you tried removing the bot as an admin(if it is meant to post)?

Answer (score 2):

Its working the same as removing a regular user, just long press the bots name and a popup will come up to remove the user...